# Create Plugin or Extension to control hardware

Tags: c#, plugins, web, cloud

I would like to know if it's possible to access the client's hardware via web browser if I create a plugin or extension. The client accesses a website (via cloud) and the plugin is responsible to acessing his serial port, parallel port, etc, and sending client's information to the cloud for processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do know, that the opposite is possible: Write a Winforms app, that only contains a browser and have it communicate with the serial port in the background - this is how I access a ticket printer in a ticket sales app.